# Google analytics onClick event not working

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I tried to implement the click event from GA but it's not computing anything

I read documentation and tried make the following changes

```
1-
<a id="home-video" onClick= "dataLayer.push('send', 'event','video', 'clique', 'video2709');" ></a>

2-
<a id="home-video" onClick="ga('send', 'event', {'video', 'clique', 'video2709'});"></a>

3-
<a id="home-video" onClick="ga('send', 'event','video', 'clique', 'video2709');"</a>

4-
<a id="home-video" onClick= "dataLayer.push('send', 'event','video', 'clique', 'video2709');"</a>


var triggerButton = document.getElementById("home-video");
  triggerButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    myModal.open();
    ga("send", "event", {
      eventCategory: "contato",
      eventAction: "clique",
      eventLabel: "botao-contato-topo"
    });
  });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to track custom events when Google Analytics is managed by Google Tag Manager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55675935/how-to-track-custom-events-when-google-analytics-is-managed-by-google-tag-manage)

Comment: Have you got the base code in the header of the pages and could you share an image of it?

Comment: The site there were only the script of GTM (google tag manager) and not of GA (google analytics), I added the TAG of GA and it worked.